# How can I make this equation look more aesthetic and balanced?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, displaystyle

I have a mathematical equation

```
$$
K = \sum_{i \in \mathcal{V}} \left\lvert i^p - \mathbbm{1}_{\{i \in \mathcal{J}\}} \cdot k^p \right\rvert
$$
```

that when compiled, looks like:

[image]

Is there a way I could lengthen the absolute value verticals and to somehow not make the p power exponentials crunch the i and the k, as well as a better indicator function. Any suggestions what I could do will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- please always provide MWE, not just code fragment
- use `$$` for switch to math mode is not LaTeX command, instead it use `\[` ... `\]` or `\begin{equation*}` ... `\end{equation*}`
- for absolute value is sensible to define new delimiters as enable `mathtools` package (see MWE below)
- your equation doesn't look so bad ...

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{bbm, mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}

\begin{document}
\[
K = \sum_{i \in \mathcal{V}} \abs*{i^p - \mathbbm{1}_{i \in \mathcal{J}}^{}{\cdot}k^p}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\lvert` and `\rvert` are versions of | that receive opening and closing delimiter spacing. Mathtools isn’t necessary for this.

Comment: @DonHosek, are you sure? Well, it is needed for `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` macro.

Comment: It’s from amsmath. Amsldoc.PDF provides a suggested definition for `\abs` using it. Although with  `\left` And `\right` even `|` will give the correct spacing.

Comment: @DonHosek -- I haven't actually tested it, but I think that just `|` may not give optimal spacing.  (It wouldn't if anything followed the right-hand vert.) Using `\lvert ... \rvert` is much better semantically.  And although it's not really needed here,  `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` does make things easier when sizing is required.

Comment: I'll have to try, but I believe that `\left|`…`\right|` works on a similar mechanism to `\left<`…`\right>`. I'll have to check later.

Comment: I didn't look closely enough at the code while on my phone. It did spark my digging a bit deeper into some of the boundary conditions around `|`…`|` vs `\lvert`…`\rvert` though. In most cases the typesetting will be identical (which may be why plain.tex didn't define `\lvert` and `\rvert`. The odd man out is if there's a unary operator inside `|`…`|`.  and this can be worked around by defining `\abs` as `|{#1}|`.